# Does Eclipse support sources in EBCDIC?

Tags: eclipse, ebcdic

I would like to work in Eclipse with sources that are in EBCDIC (IBM i version).
It seems like the standard Eclipse installation is missing EBCDIC in the list of the supported codepages for its editor. 
So, is there a way to add support of EBCDIC sources to Eclipse? 
Pls note that I'm aware about NextGen and IBM RDi but I'm looking for EBCDIC support in a standard Eclipse. 
Thanks,

Comment: Do you have an objection to EBCDIC to Unicode translation and back again? It really is NOT a matter of the code page or glyphs or fonts. It's the character set that's the problem.

Comment: Well, I need the project sources to be in EBCDIC. I'm ok for Eclipse doing the required transformation transparently for user.

Comment: Eclipse won't do it for you. However, you can maintain a shadow directory structure, where files in the Eclipse project get transformed back to the EBCDIC files in the shadow directory whenever source files change. If you need bi-directional synchronization, you have some work cut out for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify any encoding supported by the Java `Charset` class in the Text File Encoding field on the Properties > Resource for a file (or the default workspace encoding in Preferences > Workspace).

Don't be put of by the fact these fields are drop down lists, you can also type other values here.

EBCDIC comes in many flavors so `Charset` does not have a single EBCDIC value, instead there are values such as IBM500 for the code page 500 layout. So you need to know which EBCDIC code page the file uses.